# discord.py differentiate between two servers?

Tags: discord.py

Hi so I have a command for my bot `-set_event (event code)`. If that occurs on one server the change follows to another. I'm curious if there is a way to stop this from happening. Thanks.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def set_event(self, ctx, arg):
        global event_code
        event_code = arg.upper()
```

Comment: Is the command only supposed to work on a specific server(s)?  If so you can write a check that checks the id of the guild the command was invoked in.  Otherwise we'll need to see the command definition and you'll need to explain what it's supposed to do

Comment: Yes, I would like the command to only change the variable on the server that it is called in. This was an issue in the back of my head but I never thought about it until I tried it. 
I updated the question with the code.

Comment: Sounds like you need to maintain a dictionary mapping guilds to event codes.  I recommend something like `{guild.id: event_code}` so it's easily serializable

Comment: Ok, ill check that out. Thanks